# llShow that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the usual metric $d$, $\overline{B_d(0,1)}$ = $\bar{B_d}(0,1) $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the usual metric $d$, $\overline{B_d(0,1)}$ = $\bar{B_d}(0,1) $

I.e the closure of the open ball is the closed ball. How would I answer this question using

- For any two distinct points x,y in the space and any positive ϵ, there is a point z within ϵ of y, and closer to x than y is. That is, for every x≠y and ϵ>0, there is z with d(z,y)<ϵ and d(x,z)

Comment: Do you mean "the closure of the open ball?"

Comment: yes! edited thanks

Answer (score 0):

We will show that any point $y$ with $d(0,y)=1$ belongs to the closure of the open ball. Consider $x=0.$ Using the hint you are given there exists $z$ such that $$d(0,z)<d(0,x)=1,\quad d(x,z)<\epsilon.$$ This shows that

$$z\in B(y,\epsilon)\cap B(0,1)$$ or equivalently $$B(y,\epsilon)\cap B(0,1)\ne \emptyset.$$ Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we have that $y$ is in the closure.

If $d(0,y)=1+\epsilon>1$ note that

$$B(y,\epsilon/2)\cap B(0,1)= \emptyset.$$ Thus, $y$ is not in the closure.